# Java query faults & safety

Tags: java, mysql

i'm having an exam in a couple of days and there's a sample exam with a code:

```
import java.sql.*; 

public class UpdateCar { 
    public static void UpdateCarNum(int carNo, int empNo) throws SQLException { 
        Connection con = null; 
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null; 
        try { con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:default:connection"); 
             pstmt = con.prepareStatement( "UPDATE EMPLOYEES " + "SET CAR_NUMBER = ? " + "WHERE EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = " + empNo);
             pstmt.setInt(2, empNo); 
             pstmt.executeUpdate(); 
        } 
        finally {
            if (pstmt != null) pstmt.close(); 
        }
    } 
}
```

So the question is what returns an error in this code with connection to the database and bring out two ways how to improve the connection safety.

It returns an error because pstmt.setInt(2,empNo) is not defined, it should be pstmt.setInt(1,carNo).

And one way to improve safety would be to set all values in query with setInt not with variable empNo. For example

```
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES "+"SET CAR NUMBER = ? "+"WHERE EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = ?");
pstmt.setInt(1,carNo);
pstmt.setInt(2,empNo);
```

What could i do more to improve safety (second way, thought, idea - thing requested)?

Comment: The described is a coding error. Even if you do find a way to make this safer, assuring that carNo instead of empNo is used in this function, you must also be sure that the argument carNo is actually an carNo integer. What you could do is not use int in your arguments but a Car object and an Employee Object. Better yet, use an ORM like Hibernate to prevent these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: Since it's the first course of web-design patterns i don't think it expects so much of an analysis of background. Since the sample code i'm working with is the only code given, the expectation is that it's syntactically correct and would work with int carNo.

Comment: @Tom - in his example to show "a" solution it has two placeholders, not one.

Comment: @avk oh, he fixed that. Ok. Couldn't see that in the mobile app :-(.

Answer (score 1):

If an employee doesn't have a car then you can only set the car number to `0` or `-1` but not to `NULL`. If you use

```
public static void UpdateCarNum(Integer carNo, int empNo) throws SQLException {
```

then you can also support this case.

If you would use `String` for the `carNo` to support this. And if you do no checks. Then someone can inject SQL and do ugly stuff if you concatenate it like in your example. Use the advantage of the prepared statement also there by putting just a `?` in. Although then you can't use `Integer` and could use `BigDecimal` for `carNo` (because there is no `pstmt.setInteger()` only a `pstmt.setBigDecimal()`). Or alternatively use `Integer` and if it is `null` you can use `pstmt.setNull()` otherwise `pstmt.setInt(..., carNo.intValue())`.

Comment: Okay, any ideas on security?

Comment: @shawwy ok included everything I could think of now.

Comment: Gave an upvote for good point but i think this does not answer the unsolved security issue.

Comment: @shawwy maybe they expect a simple answer, like you could check that the car number is positive (or null if using answer) and throw an exception if not. And if you have additional knowledge, like say their range is from 100 to 999999 then you can check that. If you want to make it international you have to use a String for the car number because they can have `-` and `A` to `Z` and then we face the problem of SQL injection again unless doing it like in your question.

Comment: The problem is, that i don't understand that how does this go along with security of the application. What you mean should be a coding error, not a vulnerability.

Comment: @shawwy my guess is they weren't thinking about the fact that you can't do SQL injection with an `int`, but if it were a `String` then you already gave the answer yourself how to make it safer. Also there is no reason for concatenating the String if you don't want to put it on several lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a stringbuilder to spot this kind of error more quickly:

```
StringBuilder myStatement = new StringBuilder();
myStatement.append( "UPDATE EMPLOYEES" );
myStatement.append( " SET CAR_NUMBER = " + carNo );
myStatement.append( " WHERE EMPT_NO = " + emptNo );
pstmt = con.prepareStatement( myStatement.toString() );
```

and close you connection "con" in the finally-block

Answer (score 0):

Connection is not closed.  You should use try-with-resouce statement for saving resources.

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection")) {
    try (PreparedStatemt pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET CAR_NUMBER = ? WHERE EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = ?")) {
        pstmt.setInt(1, carNo); 
        pstmt.setInt(2, empNo); 
        pstmt.executeUpdate(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `pstmt.close()` does not close `con`.  In `try (T r = ...) { ... }`, T must implement interface java.lang.AutoCloseable.  Then `r.close()` is called at the end of the statement.  Connection, PreparedStatement and ResultSet implement the interface.